# Connect one object to many objects of same type

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

So I have the following setup:

`|---- Device[1]
Controller ---+---- Device[2]
              |---- Device[3]
              |       :
              |---- Device[x]`

Each object is in its own thread.

For communications from Deivce[x] to controller this is relatively easy, I just connect all the device signals to a slot in the controller and pass the device index as a parameter so the controller can identify which device.

However, I am unsure how is best to do the same in the other direction (controller to device). The best I have come up with is a similar scheme, where I connect a signal in controller to a slot in each of the devices. I can still pass an index so if the messages is directed at Device[1], then Device[2] and Device[3] can ignore it. However, is this a huge overhead in terms of data repetition? - i.e. is the data sent three times?

Is there a better way?

**edit 1**
I have edited the example to show that I can have any number of devices.. its not hard-coded number, so if I need a signal/slot for each device the signals will need to be created dynamically.

**edit 2**
It seems you can call methods directly using something like:
`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(devices[x], "handleMessage", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QByteArray msgData)));`

This allows me to invoke a slot on any object (queued, so its thread safe) and pass my data.... but it feels like I am breaking fundamental Qt slots/signals methodology if I do this.

Comment: you can do the same thing. Put the device index in the signal. then in a private slot with a switch statement or something else check which device must receive the signal and send it to it.

Comment: @Jepessen I think this is what I was suggesting already? - the problem is if I connect a signal to multiple device slots, will the data be sent three times? If I create seperate signals for each device - how can I create a signal dynamically (as there can be any number of devices)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have not found much on the internet about this issue. There are some possibilities I have seen people try to use/answer the question with:

**1. QSignalMapper**

This has its limitations which I have commented on in ram's answer.

**2. Invoke Target Slot Directly**

You can invoke the target slot directly (yes across thread boundary!), this can be done as shown below (just showing this for completeness):

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(devices[x], "handleMessage", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QByteArray msgData)));`

Where:

- Devices[x] is a pointer to the device object
- "handleMessage" is the name of the slot function
- Queued connection is used to make sure its thread safe and not called in the calling thread.
- Q_ARG(...) is an argument that is passed to the slot, in this case a QByteArray called msgData. Note: you can have multiple of these.

This works fine, but it breaks the whole methodology of slots/signals, because we are invoking a slot in a foreign object without a signal or connection... effectively punching a hole through the wall and grabbing what we want - so it also breaks the encapsulation principals too (not the mention thread boundary).

**3. Dynamic Slot Creation**

I read this in the qt documentation [here, about halfway down](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html), but it looks like horrible code to have to write/maintain so I did not even try this.

**My Proposed Solution**

So finally I decided I have to dream something up. Because I only know how many devices I will have at run time, creating signals dynamically as each device registers is appealing, but as described above, not very nice.

However we can instantiate objects dynamically, where the object contains a signal that can be used to map one-to-one to a device. Effectively creating a "postbox" object where its signal can be connected to the equivalent device at run-time. The setup is shown below:

`|-------------------------|
|                         |
|             Postbox[1]--+------Device[1]
| Controller  Postbox[2]--+------Device[2]
|             Postbox[3]--+------Device[3]
|                         |   :
|             Postbox[x]--+------Device[x]
|                         |
|-------------------------|`

Where the controller object contains an array (or vector) of postbox objects. For each device that registers with the controller it creates a new instance of postbox, connects its signal to the devices slot and then adds the postbox to the array. Then to post a message to, for example device[3], the controller simply calls a function like `postboxes[3].postmessage(msgData);`, the postmessage function emits the signal that is connected to the device[3].

As far as I can tell, this is the only "correct/simple" way to do this because qt slots/signals does not seem to be setup to do message routing as such. Please someone correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: why not just use `static` `QHash` or `QMap`. This is how I once implemented when I need to figure out object count during run time.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Thanks, its a valid point and I will probably use a QVector.  But the container type is not really the point I was trying to make. The important part is that there is one object per device allowing a one to one slot/signal connection. How the "post" objects are stored is (in my mind) a trivial implementation matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QSignalMapper`.

```
Controller::Controller()
{
    QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i) {
        Device* d = new Device(...);
        connect(d, SIGNAL(somethingHappened)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        signalMapper->setMapping(d, i);
    }

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(handleDevice(int)));
}

void Controller::handleDevice(int id)
{
 .....
}
```

More here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, the signal mapper is limited to a single passable parameter, and that parameter needs to be the index or something?. This is what has deterred me from trying to use it in the past...